# Wordpress site displays replacement character � in posts

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding

Launched a new WP site about 1 month ago, and there were no issues at the time. Now there are instances of this character (�) inserting itself into posts. Looks to be happening where an open tag begins. Some sort of character encoding problem? Only happening in posts, not pages, so possibly a database issue?

Comment: The replacement character is usually a client side problem: the selected font cannot display such character (or character combination). But it could help, if you download the page, and you check on some good editor what character cannot be displayed (maybe just a emoticon or a separation mark (like list items). In that case you can change it, so that most users will not have such problem. Lastly if the font in question is a glyph-icon font (so with special icons), maybe there is some configuration problem and you do not deliver the font (or it is not more in the correct place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't copied and pasted the content from another editor like Word, have you?

It's encoding causing the problem, where Wordpress doesn't recognise the character you're using. If you hand code it rather than using the visual editor you shouldn't see it, and the most likely cause is inheriting the character from a piece of software that you have previously edited in.

Comment: Thank you. Deleting and re-coding all the tags worked. I'm still at a loss to explain why it started happening in the first place. My only theory is my hosting company updated some server/database software and it no longer recognizes these characters.

Comment: If you get the question mark it is a character that the ascii value for is not recognised in the character set it is being displayed in. You see it a lot on line breaks and spaces in Word documents when they're pasted into CMS. That's why going into the code for the particular post/page should reveal them.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Open the `wp-config.php` file in a text editor such as notepad (the `wp-config.php` file can be found on the directory where you installed WordPress).

Step 2) Find the following two lines and comment them out:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

They should look like the following after you comment them out:

```
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
//define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Step 3) Now upload the updated `wp-config.php` file to your webhost (overwriting the old one).

Comment: I tried that. It didn't resolve the issue, and introduced new problems.